# How to catch SocketException using the http library?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-http

This problem has already been pointed out by others (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810051/cannot-catch-socketexception)). Althought I may have understood the cause, I still haven't found a solution when using the higher-level `http` library.
For example:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

// yes, pwd is String, it's just a test...
Future<Response> login(String user, String pwd) {
  final authHeader = encodeBasicCredentials(user, pwd);
  return get(
    'http://192.168.0.100:8080/login',
    headers: <String, String>{
    HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: authHeader,
    },
  ));
}
```

I can't find a way to catch a `SocketException` that is thrown, for example, if the host can't be reached (in my case, wrong host ip).
I have tried wrapping the `await` in `try/catch`, or using `Future.catchError`.

This is a stacktrace of the exception:

```
[ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 4036): SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 192.168.0.100, port = 35588
E/flutter ( 4036): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:30:23)
E/flutter ( 4036): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4036): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:171:38)
E/flutter ( 4036): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4036): #2      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:34:5)
E/flutter ( 4036): #3      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:47:34)
E/flutter ( 4036): #4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:167:20)
E/flutter ( 4036): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4036): #5      get (package:http/http.dart:47:3)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change `login` to be `async` so that you can await the response. That allows you to catch the exception (and, for example, return `null` instead of the `Response`).

```
Future<Response> login(String user, String pwd) async {
  final String authHeader = encodeBasicCredentials(user, pwd);
  try {
    return await get(
        'http://192.168.0.100:8080/login',
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: authHeader,
        },
      );
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I kinda feel ashamed that I hadn't thought of this myself :)

Comment: @Richard Heap I am confuced about try{}catch and try{}on socketException{}. what if i used 'On SocketException instead of Catch in your exception handling?

Comment: `on` is a shorthand for filtering the type of exception you want to handle in a particular block of code. See: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#catch

Answer (score 10):

You can check the type of the exception and treat it accordingly something like:

```
Future<Response> login(String user, String pwd) async {
  final String authHeader = encodeBasicCredentials(user, pwd);
  try {
    return await get(
        'http://192.168.0.100:8080/login',
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: authHeader,
        },
      );
  } catch (e) {
    if(e is SocketException){
       //treat SocketException
       print("Socket exception: ${e.toString()}");
    }
    else if(e is TimeoutException){
       //treat TimeoutException
       print("Timeout exception: ${e.toString()}");
    }
    else print("Unhandled exception: ${e.toString()}");
  }
}
```

Probly better off making an error handler lib, so you can just call a function like `handleException(e);` on the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

SocketException on http

```
 try {

    } on SocketException {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to catch the error is to call a method on the get method by using the catch error argument like so. This method of the get method can catch others types of errors, not only the socket exception. Look at the code below for more

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Future<Response> login(String user, String pwd) {
final authHeader = encodeBasicCredentials(user, pwd);
return get(
 'http://192.168.0.100:8080/login',
      headers: <String, String>{
    HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION: authHeader,
    },
     ).catchError(error){
    //you can now do your error handling in this block
       });
     }
 }
```